# optimal table design mysql with primay key and varchar value

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a table which is used by two processes.

The table looks like:

```
valueID (INT PRIMARY AUTO INCREMENT)
value (VARCHAR 100 UNIQUE)
```

- process 1 does query's like `SELECT valueID FROM table WHERE value = '$val'` at a rate of >250 per second
- process 2 does the opposite: `SELECT value FROM table WHERE valueID = '$valid'` at a rate of >400 per second

So this table gets hit big and is quite large as well> over 50 millions rows and growing fast.
I currently experience slowing down of performance since the table is growing in size. I want to optimize it. Thinking of partitioning but of of the other will be hit negative in performance.
Currently MyISAM but InnoDB is possible as well.

Any ideas on what the most optimal setup for this table can be?

Comment: Do you have the following multi-column covering indexes: `(value, valueID)` and `(valueID, value)`?

Comment: Have you done anything with your config parameters? Not all configurations are created equal.

Comment: We use the primary and unique index. Tests with combined index slowed everything down (with both indexes present explain even uses the primary and not the combined)

Answer (score 0):

You may devide the rate in a range like

```
SELECT valueID FROM table WHERE value = '$val' at a rate>=250 and rate<=400
```

AND

```
SELECT valueID FROM table WHERE value = '$val' at a rate>=401 and rate<=600
```

Comment: the rate is the number of query's per second per proces....this needs to become even higher

Comment: in this case you can use solr search that return rows in less than a second from a table containing millions of rows.

Comment: proces 2 acts on the response of an search engine like solr which returns id's and output needs to be value....using this table in such an index is not possible since id's and values need to be available in real time